# data not displaying in a custom cell of a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I'm new to iOS.

I'm trying to display a data in a `UILabel` within a custom `Table View Cell`. The `IBOutlet` has been connected as it is highlighted when i hover over the connection node in the sidebar. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The print statements are also correct, but the cell is still empty as shown below:

[image]

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Follow a UITableView's basic tutorial with Swift. Here is a link: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Answer (score 2):

just make sure in storyboard. Are You using custom cell or Existing cell?
if existing cell then select table -> attribute inspector-> dynamic cell 0 to 1.
and select cell and write its identifier name and use this name in cellforrowAtindexpath delegate method in uitableview class.

if You are using custom cell then create a class with uitablecell.
Go to storyboard select cell -> identity inspector select your custom class cell. 
Now select cell put label and pass it outlet to custom cell.
Now select uitableview class go to cellforrowAtindex path method and create an instance of your customcell class and call label outlet and other ui outlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with tables, look at the protocols UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. 
There you have the functions to fill the table with cells
like:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
 numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)
 tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:     NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```